# Turn on / off Conversation threads

Tags: email, yahoo-mail

I have just purchased a Samsung A51 / S51 and use Yahoo Mail. Emails now are placed in conversation threads which makes viewing confused. Apparently you can toggle this option on or off either via Settings directly or via Profile.  However this option does not seem to show up in my Settings and accessing my Profile is not so simple and / or seems not to make any difference. It is almost as if someone has gone to great lengths to make this simple operation complicated. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: I assume you are using the official [Yahoo mail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail)? Do you know that you can use any other IMAP capable mail app? Use the following settings: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/set-imap-sln4075.html

Comment: Yes I am using what I believe is the official Yahoo email app on the mobile which seems to sync with Yahoo on my desktop. I would not know how to start adjusting IMAP server settings and if I did I would be afraid of doing damage which I could not repair!
From articles that I have read it would seem to be a simple operation to switch off conversation threads if one can work out the route through the menu options to do this - which on my S51 / A51 is not clear.